# Form Not Submitting PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having some trouble, I am trying to submit a form with php and phpmailer.

So what I did is trying to make a form following w3school complete form example and then I wondered if I could send it through email. I found phpmailer and I tried using it but it is not sending.

I am using the $contactsend to know if I can send form or not (after the validation have been done). So in case $contactsend is 0 then I cannot send and if it is 1 then I can send the form.

However I am almost sure that there is an issue with it but I don't know why.
How can I understand what is going wrong?

Here is the code I have :

```
<?php

$contactnameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $subjectErr = $messageErr = "";
$contactname = $email = $phone = $subject = $message = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  $contactsend= 1;

  if (empty($_POST["contactname"])) {
    $contactnameErr = "* Name is required";
    $contactsend= 0;
  } else {
    $contactname = test_input($_POST["contactname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$contactname)) {
      $contactnameErr = "* Only letters and white space allowed"; 
      $contactsend= 0;
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["contactemail"])) {
    $contactemailErr = "* Email is required";
    $contactsend= 0;
  } else {
    $contactemail = test_input($_POST["contactemail"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($contactemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $contactemailErr = "* Invalid email format"; 
      $contactsend= 0;
    }
  }



   if (empty($_POST["contactphone"])) {
    $contactphoneErr = "* Phone is required";
    $contactsend= 0;
  } else {
    $contactphone = test_input($_POST["contactphone"]);
    $contactsend= 0;
  }



   if (empty($_POST["contactsubject"])) {
    $contactsubjectErr = "* Subject is required";
    $contactsend= 0;
  } else {
    $contactsubject = test_input($_POST["contactsubject"]);
    $contactsend= 0;
  }


    if (empty($_POST["contactmessage"])) {
    $contactmessageErr = "* Message is required";
    $contactsend= 0;
  } else {
    $contactmessage = test_input($_POST["contactmessage"]);
    $contactsend= 0;
  }

  echo $contactsend;

  if($contactsend== 1)
  {
      //send mail
      $message = "\nSpecial Events , Contact Us . \nName : " .  $contactname . "\nEmail : " .  $contactemail .   "\nPhone : " .  $contactphone 
        . "\nSubject : " .  $contactsubject ."\nMessage : " .  $contactmessage;  
        require("/home/specialeventsleb/public_html/phpmailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
        $mail->Port       = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->Username = 'email1';
        $mail->Password = 'password1';
        $mail->SetFrom('email1', 'FromEmail');
        $mail->AddAddress('email1', 'ToEmail');
        $mail->AddAddress('email2', 'ToEmail1');
        $mail->AddAddress('email3', 'ToEmail2');
        $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
        $mail->Timeout = 2000;
        $mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {echo "debug level $level; message: $str";}; 
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'echo';
        $mail->Subject = 'Message from Special Events Website';
        $mail->Body    = $message;
        $mail->send();
}

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

?>


<div id="ContactUs">
<!--<img class="ComputerBanner" src="Pictures/map/ContactUsBanner.png" />-->
<img class="MobileBanner" src="Pictures/map/ContactUsBannerMobile.png" />
<div class="ContactBox">
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
    <h2>SEND US A MESSAGE!</h2>
    <span>We'd be happy to hear from you.</span>
    <input name="contactname" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="<?php echo $contactname;?>"/> <span class="error"> <?php echo $contactnameErr;?></span>
    <input name="contactemail" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="<?php echo $contactemail;?>" /><span class="error"> <?php echo $contactemailErr;?></span>
    <input name="contactphone" placeholder="Phone #" type="text" value="<?php echo $contactphone;?>" /><span class="error"> <?php echo $contactphoneErr;?></span>
    <input name="contactsubject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" value="<?php echo $contactsubject;?>" /><span class="error"> <?php echo $contactsubjectErr;?></span>
    <textarea name="contactmessage" placeholder="Message"><?php echo $contactmessage;?></textarea><span class="error"> <?php echo $contactmessageErr;?></span>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="contact-button" />
 </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the operations you're checking with `if($contactsend== 1)` are not called because your script forces `$contactsend = 0` checking "contactsubject", "contactphone", "contactmessage"..
Then you have to set these

```
 $mail->SetFrom('email1', 'FromEmail');
 $mail->AddAddress('email1', 'ToEmail');
 $mail->AddAddress('email2', 'ToEmail1');
 $mail->AddAddress('email3', 'ToEmail2');
```

with valid email addresses.. 
Example with

`$mail->AddAddress($contactemail, 'ToEmail');`

which get the value from the POST

For any other infos read this 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: yes you are right I was forcing the contactsend  remove it from those 3 fields after test data , it works !